# SQL - faster to filter by large table or small table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the below query which takes a while to run, since ir_sales_summary is ~ 2 billion rows:

```
select c.ChainIdentifier, s.SupplierIdentifier, s.SupplierName, we.Weekend, 

sum(sales_units_cy) as TY_unitSales, sum(sales_cost_cy) as TY_costDollars, sum(sales_units_ret_cy) as TY_retailDollars,

sum(sales_units_ly) as LY_unitSales, sum(sales_cost_ly) as LY_costDollars, sum(sales_units_ret_ly) as LY_retailDollars

from ir_sales_summary i

left join Chains c
on c.ChainID = i.ChainID

inner join Suppliers s
on s.SupplierID = i.SupplierID

inner join tmpWeekend we
on we.SaleDate = i.saledate

where year(i.saledate) = '2017'

group by c.ChainIdentifier, s.SupplierIdentifier, s.SupplierName, we.Weekend
```

(Worth noting, it takes roughly 3 hours to run since it is using a view that brings in data from a legacy service)

I'm thinking there's a way to speed up the filtering, since I just need the data from 2017. Should I be filtering from the big table (i) or be filtering from the much smaller weekending table (which gives us just the week ending dates)?

Comment: To really speed the query you probably want to partition `ir_sales_summary` by year or month.

Comment: Your use of the `YEAR()` function prevents SQL Server from using an index on `saledate`, which I'm assuming exists.  `where year(i.saledate) = '2017'` should  be `where i.saledate >= cast('20170101' as datetime2) and i.saledate < cast('20180101' as datetime2)`.  Use whatever data type `saledate` is if it's not a datetime2.

Comment: It is worth looking at the execution plan for this. Also, rather than using a Year function in the filter, does it help to change the condition to "i.saledate > '1/1/2017' ? On another side note, the year function returns an integer, so remove the quotes from 2017 as some kind of implicit conversion is happening there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the year function, makes perfect sense.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't view the execution plan on this server, gotta love DBAs and their permissions lol....

Comment: then they should be optimizing this for you...

Comment: Should of, could of...

Comment: Changing the year filer to a cast sped it up significantly, now runs in 30 minutes vs. 3 hours

Comment: As far as the original question of faster by filtering little or big table first, doesn't the query optimizer do this behind the scenes anyway? I'm not sure though. Good indexing will likely help the most (which also means changing the filtering on i.salesdate to actually use an index).

Comment: @tc_NYC trying to optimize a query without an execution plan is like trying to drive a car without a gas gauge and speedometer. You're just guessing where the problem is rather than getting detailed information. If the DBA prevents giving this information, then they take the responsibility to help out with troublesome queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This might help, joining a static table as first table in query onto a fact/dynamic table will impact query performance i believe.

```
SELECT c.ChainIdentifier
    ,s.SupplierIdentifier
    ,s.SupplierName
    ,i.Weekend
    ,sum(sales_units_cy) AS TY_unitSales
    ,sum(sales_cost_cy) AS TY_costDollars
    ,sum(sales_units_ret_cy) AS TY_retailDollars
    ,sum(sales_units_ly) AS LY_unitSales
    ,sum(sales_cost_ly) AS LY_costDollars
    ,sum(sales_units_ret_ly) AS LY_retailDollars
FROM Suppliers s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT we
        ,weeekend
        ,supplierid
        ,chainid
        ,sales_units_cy
        ,sales_cost_cy
        ,sales_units_ret_cy
        ,sales_units_ly
        ,sales_cost_ly
        ,sales_units_ret_ly
    FROM ir_sales_summary i
    INNER JOIN tmpWeekend we
        ON we.SaleDate = i.saledate
    WHERE year(i.saledate) = '2017'
    ) i
    ON s.SupplierID = i.SupplierID
INNER JOIN Chains c
    ON c.ChainID = i.ChainID
GROUP BY c.ChainIdentifier
    ,s.SupplierIdentifier
    ,s.SupplierName
    ,i.Weekend
```